# Create local DB in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I want to have a database application which is intended to develop with C# .I will be having only 4 tables in the database.So I prefer to have a local DB ( not a external database ) & once I try to add a database ( called servise -based database ) in visual studio I ended up with a error message saying that I must have sql sever 2008 Express.But I have installed sql sever express 2008 on my laptop.What should I do to have local DB( I just want to develop a portable software which will not be asking for any third party application to run).
I have attached screen shot of error message.

Thanks in Advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using any MS SQL database considering installation of MS SQL Server or using remote instance of SQL Server. There is no other way to use SQL functionality i
I'm afraid.

You might consider [SqLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html) or [Sql Compact](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17876) if you don't want to isntall any software.

Also you might consider such simple solutions as XML or JSON as background data storage solution.